# Which method is faster for replacing the last occurrence of a substring in a string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, optimization

I have a `str`ing which is a combination of "S"s and "C"s. There is at least one occurrence of each.

I want to find the last occurrence of "CS" and change it to "SC".

I have two methods (so far):

```
P = P[::-1].replace("SC", "CS", 1)[::-1]
```

and

```
P = P[:P.rfind("CS")] + "SC" + P[P.rfind("CS") + 2:]
```

**Which line is likely to be faster?
Also, is there a quicker way to achieve what I'm doing?**

Comment: You can test this by running both functions <many> times and measuring the time difference between start and end using time.time().

Comment: You should look into the `timeit` module. If you are working in the iPython console, look into the `%timeit` magic command. You can answer this kind of question ("which line is likely to be faster?") on your own.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is one way:

```
>>> s = 'CSsomethingSCSagainCSsomething'
>>> 'SC'.join(s.rsplit('CS', 1))
CSsomethingSCSagainSCsomething
```

**Syntax**:

```
new_substring.join(str.rsplit(old_substring, occurance))
```

Comment: it beats OP attempt in my bench.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Also, so this will only replace the last occurrence, right?

Comment: @Adi219 but I benched my answer afterwards, and it appears that it was slower... yes, it replaces the last occurrence.

Comment: @Adi219 Yes, it replaces the last occurrence only.

Comment: Thanks! This helps a lot :)

Comment: @Adi219 Probably you may wait for other answers and accept only if you find this one good.

Comment: @theausome I doubt python can do it any faster. Let's see.

Comment: @Adi219 you should accept it. You can accept another one if a better one arises (but I doubt it!)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre BTW, I'm doing Google Code Jam today and I want to make sure my code is as optimised as possible, so this will help a lot! :)

Comment: If you'll be doing this multiple times, you can save ~12% by caching the lookup of `'SC'.join`. `x = 'SC'.join; x(s.rsplit('CS', 1))`. (You can't apply the same trick to `s.rsplit` because, presumably, `s` would be different every time you use this.)

Comment: (And using `methodcaller('rsplit', 'CS', 1)(s)` is slightly slower than just using `s.rsplit('CS', 1)`.)

Comment: @chepner You're right in that I'm going to repeat this operation many times (and with different strings each time). Please could you elaborate on (both of) your points? (As I don't fully understand)

Comment: This example code, as shown, doesn't run as it has unbalanced parentheses.

Comment: @cdlane edited now. That was a mistake I made on my second edit. Thanks.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre There seems to be an answer which claims to do it about 20% faster

Answer (score 2):

In my crude timing, this beats the `rsplit()` and `join()` solution by 20%:

```
head, _, tail = string.rpartition('CS')
new_string = f"{head}SC{tail}"
```

I does depend on Python 3.6+, of course.

Comment: yes it's faster. But with a classical `format(head=head,...)` it doesn't work as fast. Python 3.6 only. Nice